Exec form in docker file for CMD with parameter
I'm trying to use the exec form in a dockerfile CMD:
CMD ["node", "main.js"]

But how do I have to handle additional parameters?
CMD npx next start -p $PORT_VALUE

Should it be
CMD ["npx", "next", "start", "-p", "$PORT_VALUE"]

or
CMD ["npx", "next", "start", "-p $PORT_VALUE"]

?

Neither. Variable substitution is done by the shell, so you need to run a shell to do it. I.e.
CMD npx next start -p $PORT_VALUE 

Or you can run the shell yourself in exec form
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "npx next start -p $PORT_VALUE"]


Note that those two forms run the exact same command: Docker wraps shell-form CMD in the current SHELL setting, by default /bin/sh -c.
